# Mistake in the Algorithm Design Manual?

Tags: integers

Look at this excerpt from the Algorithm Design Manual by Skiena, 2nd Edition

[image]

The sum of the first $n$ **even** integers? Surely, the two sums given do not include only even numbers, right? Is this a mistake on the author's part, or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like a mistake, yes. Either they wanted to use $2i$, which simplifies to 2 * what they write then. Or, the "even" should not be in the sentence. I consider the second more likely since the second half of the sentence doesn't make sense for only even integers, either.

Comment: What's intended is  "The sum of the first even $n$ integers ... ". As written, it's in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an explanation for the [Gaussian sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) (funfact: in German it is called "little Gauss"). Hence, as you recognized, the **even** here is not correct.

The equality of these sums can be shown inductively or simply by putting them into [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20i,%20i%3D1%20to%20n%20%3D%20sum%20(i%2B(n-i%2B1)),%20i%3D1%20to%20n%2F2)

The "even" case works like Raphael stated, but doesn't seem to have any intellectual value.